# Game maker refuses to compile and run game, with error message "Unable to find game"

Tags: game-maker

I am currently doing a project in a fresh installation of Game Maker Studio, version 1.4.1499. When I attempt to build and run the project (using the run button, the run menu option, or by pressing F5), it comes up with the following output:

```
Asset Compile finished: 11:07:49 AM
-----------------------------------------------------------
executing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gm_ttt_64280\gm_ttt_91991\game.win
-----------------------------------------------------------
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\GameMaker-Studio\Runner.exe"  -game "C:\Users\Juggernaut\AppData\Local\Temp\gm_ttt_64280\gm_ttt_91991\game.win"

RunnerLoadGame: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gm_ttt_64280\gm_ttt_91991\game.win
#########################################################################
####!!!!$$$$$$ pwd - C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gm_ttt_64280\gm_ttt_91991\
#########################################################################
RunnerLoadGame() - C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\\game.win
Checking if INIFile C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\/options.ini Exists
!!!!No INI File C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\/options.ini
Reading File C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\\game.win
Error! not allowing save with filename 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\game.win'
FAILED to load File C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\\game.win
```

I do not know if this is a problem with the way I have set up Game Maker, the project itself, or something else, but any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Try re-install GMS.
Also try build with YYC if you don't used it, or try build without YYC if you used it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the last 2 lines:

> Error! not allowing save with filename
>   'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\game.win' FAILED to load File
>   C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\game.win

Apparently you can't save the game with this filename. Try another filename, but I hardly think that's the problem. I think closing Gamemaker studio, and re-opening it with administrator rights (right mouse button, open as administrator). Could be that you don't have enough rights to write in the AppData folder.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. I fixed it by running the application as a admin. I hope it worked for you and yes this is a little bit a late answer..